# Equals $1$ on anything but stage $0$

Tags: functions

I need a formula that works as follows:

Where $n = 0$

Answer = $0$

Where $n > 0$

Answer = $1$

Comment: Sign[n], assuming n>=0

Comment: what would this be as an equation?

Answer (score 1):

As HammyTheGreek suggests, [the sign function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sign.html) works perfectly here, but there are certainly other ways of representing this if you want.

The simple definition which jumps to mind is piecewise:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\\1&\text{if }x>0\end{cases}$$

A more arcane possible definition is
$$f(x)=\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow 0^+}x^a$$

Of course, these are all effectively the same thing, and if you want to make what you are doing clear, the piecewise definition is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't 100% clear to me - what counts a formula? what is our language? - but anyhow you may find this useful.

Let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be given as follows:

- $f(0) = 0$
- $f(n) = 1$ whenever $n \neq 0$.

Then $f$ can represented by the following "high school" formula

$$f(n) = 1-0^n.$$

This makes use of the fact that $0^0=1.$

(Some would argue that this is a mere a convention; personally, I tend to regard it as a theorem.)